# What is the name of the daemon process of mysql in OS X?

Tags: macos, mysql, daemon

I have just installed mysql in OS X and this code works fine:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "information_schema";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "";
String password = "";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, password);

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from CHARACTER_SETS");
while(res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString("CHARACTER_SET_NAME"));
}

conn.close();
```

so I assume everything is fine. But in Activity Monitor I can not see the daemon process:

[image]

Why do not I see something like **mysqld** ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps have Activity Monitor set to display only your processes - I see all of the processes in the screenshot are owned by your user? Set it to display *All Processes* and you should see `mysqld` (I'm not sure how you installed MySQL but I'm guessing it's not running as your user).